# How do I switch a pruned node to "neutrino mode"?

Tags: bitcoin-core, lightning-network, pruning, compact-client-side-block-filters

According to [Lightning Lab's documentation](https://github.com/lightninglabs/docs.lightning.engineering/blob/master/lightning-network-tools/lnd/enable-neutrino-mode-in-bitcoin-core.md), Bitcoin Core can be run in "neutrino mode" to serve block data without storing transactions.

I've been running Bitcoin Core in pruning mode and everything is okay. Now I would like to enable this mode to serve data for `lnd`. The documentation says that adding these parameters will set up Bitcoin Core to run in "neutrino mode":

```
blockfilterindex=1
peerblockfilters=1
```

When I add them, Bitcoin Core gives this error:

> Error: basic block filter index best block of the index goes beyond
> pruned data. Please disable the index or reindex (which will download
> the whole blockchain again)

Of course, it is necessary to re-download the blockchain. So my questions are:

- **Will this configuration cause Bitcoin Core to store the entire blockchain, or will it just keep the headers and continue pruning the blocks?**
- **How can a reindex be triggered?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running a sufficiently recent version? If you are running an older version, you would need to have the full blockchain archive to serve compact client-side block filters.
Originally `blockfilterindex` and pruning were exclusive features. This was only changed recently when PR[#15946](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/15946) allowed serving compact client-side block filters from pruned nodes. The feature was included in the **Bitcoin Core v22.0** release.

You should be able to trigger the reindex by stopping your Bitcoin Core, and then starting Bitcoin Core with the `-reindex` startup parameter once.

Comment: thanks! I'm trying this at the moment, still redownloading the blockchain

Answer (score 3):

Bitcoin Core doesn't run in Neutrino mode, it can only **serve** compact filters. Neutrino is a Lightning Lab's implementation of BIP157 and BIP158 basic filter type. It is a standalone backend, and you can run lnd **without** Bitcoin Core.
Moreover, the only way to compute the missing filters is to download all blocks again, compute the filters and then prune again.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question